# What kind of green flower is this?

Tags: identification, houseplants

[image]

[image: plant identification]

Plant has probably never blossomed. I suppose it was not very expensive to buy. Thank you for any hints.[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This plant has a few names and is sold under variations of it. You might find it called Dracaena demerensis, Dracaena "Compacta", D. fragrans 'Compacta.
Plant relationships have only gotten more complicated with dna analysis and the only sure thing is that is a [Dracaena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracaena_(plant)).

I notice yours has the brown tips characteristic of over watering or using water with chlorine or fluoride in it.

This plant grows slowly and not does not require fertilizer on a regular basis. The flowers are insignificant.  Pests are few, weakened plants can get mealy bug.  More light and less water are recommended for indoor cultivation.

Comment: Thank you for advice. I thought it is something else seeing wikipedia page. It had long stem, there. But I googled  "Dracaena deremensis"

https://www.ceskestavby.cz/rostliny/dracinec-dracaena-deremensis/

and it is quite similar, and they also write here that different varieties have just green leaves (Janet Craig) or with white stripes. Our plant is year or so old, so it is quite small, now. In the link they write it grows slowly and can reach 120-150 cm, which is quite surprising.

Plant is not watered with chlorine water, but maybe it is too less watered.

Comment: Our guess at home was it is something like bromelia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bromelia
but we are pure amateurs.